# Do domain authority (DA) and page authority (PA) rates and spam score contribute to SEO?

Tags: seo, technical-seo, domain-authority, moz

Do DA and PA ratios contribute to SEO? And if the spam score increases at these rates, will it cause any harm to my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DA and PA rates are based entirely on backlinks and page quality based on Moz algorithm. It has no affiliation with Google. It's just that people pay attention to these values for some reason when they want to buy a promotional article. I don't think these values are important. As for the spam score, the Moz site can't know your google reject list, so it can't know if it's rejecting your malicious links. So I think spam score is redundant and irrelevant value for google.